# How to display taxanomy info from latest posts

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, posts, country

I need to display an icon associated to a custom Wordpress taxonomy. The code for the taxonomy is:

```
$labels = array(
    'name' =>  'Country/State/City' ,
    'singular_name' =>  'Genre' ,
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Country/State/City' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Country/State/City' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Country/State/City' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Genre:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Country/State/City' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Country/State/City' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Country/State/City' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Country/State/City' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Country/State/City' ),    ); 
    register_taxonomy( 'location', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'labels' => $labels, 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
    }
```

I created a folder inside my theme folder which contains the country flags (Spain.png, France.png, etc)

I need to display a list with the latest posts titles with the flag next to it.

So I thought I could do the loop and get, let's say, the latest 10 posts from a post category, display it's title and the icon next to it would be the "path-to-image-folder/taxonomy-country.png"

I don't know how to do it... can anyone give me a hand to jump start me please?

edit

So I got to this:

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '15' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        $terms = get_the_terms( $recent->ID, 'location' );
        $flagimg='<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/flags/'.$terms[0]->slug.'.png" alt="'.$terms[0]->name.'" border="0" />';
        echo '<li class="country-'.$terms[0]->slug.'"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >'.$flagimg.' '.$recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
}
?>
</ul>
```

but the img src link i get is: http://inovve.net/expoff/wp-content/themes/inovve/images/flags/.png

ie the taxonomy name is missing.... :/

Comment: So my $terms[0]->slug is empty...

Any idea why???

Comment: $recent->ID returns null value.... But it shouldn't...